# Error : Could not find the correct Provider<List<PostModel>>above this ListPost Widget

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, widget, provider

Im having problem with this error. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Gxi.png)

This is my main.dart

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const HousemateHeavenApp());
}


class HousemateHeavenApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const HousemateHeavenApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Role();
            } else {
              return Auth();
            }
          },
        )
      ) 
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my list.dart where i use the provider

```
class ListPost extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListPost> createState() => _ListPostState();
}

class _ListPostState extends State<ListPost> {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final posts = Provider.of<List<PostModel>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final post = posts[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(post.user),
          subtitle: Text(post.house),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I try google what to do and get answer that I need to set my MaterialApp as a child of Provider. The problem is, i dont know how to set this. Can anyone tell me how to set it ?